# Using entries() in a for-of loop, iterating over an HTMLCollection

Tags: javascript, for-loop, htmlcollection, for-of-loop

I'm aware that in a `for-of` loop, there is the ability to utilise the `Array.entries()` method. This works great normally, as outlined - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries.

However, if I try to do something like:

```
for (const [i, foo] of document.getElementsByClassName('foo').entries())
{
  console.log(`i = ${i}, foo = ${foo}`);
}
```

I get told that:

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName.entries is not a function or its return value is not iterable
```

I know I can just use a good old regular for loop... But:

- Why doesn't it work?
- Am I misunderstanding something?
- Can I get it to work the way I want it to (other than using a regular for loop)?

My best guess is that an `HTMLCollection` isn't a standard array, and so doesn't have a numeric index as such...

Comment: You are correct. You can spread the html collection in an array to be able to use the entries method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entries method is available for arrays. However, `getElementsByClassName` does not return an array. Instead it returns an `HTMLCollection`. You need to first convert it into array. There are two ways you can do that:

1. Using `Array.prototype.slice`

```js
function toArray(arr) {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(arr);
}

toArray(document.getElementsByClassName('foo'));
```

2. Using ES6 spread

```js
function toArray(arr) {
  return [...arr];
}

toArray(document.getElementsByClassName('foo'));
```

Comment: 3. Using `Array.from` - you don't need to create your own method for that

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` doesn't give an array, but NodeList

```js
for (const [i, foo] of [].entries.call(document.getElementsByClassName('foo')))
{
  console.log(`i = ${i}, foo = `, foo);
}
```